# TSLint: Backbone get() called outside of owning model meaning

Tags: node.js, typescript, tslint

I am using Microsoft's `tslint-microsoft-contrib` tslint configuration and I am really happy with it. However there is one rule which warns me about my code. I don't understand the rule description text or how I could solve this more elegant.

> [tslint] Backbone get() called outside of owning model:
>   this.client.get('locations') (no-backbone-get-set-outside-model)

**Code:**

```
import * as Redis from 'ioredis';
import config from './config';

export class RedisWrapper {
  private client: Redis.Redis

  constructor(redisUrl: string) {
    this.client = new Redis(redisUrl)
  }

  public async getLocations(): ILocation[] {
    const locationsResponse: string = await this.client.get('locations')
  }
}
```

In this line the tslint warning pops up: `const locationsResponse: string = await this.client.get('locations')`

**The question:**

Originally I faced this issue at a different place in my project and I thought I was supposed to write wrapper methods with typedefs, but I wasn't able to make tslint happy with that either. Can someone enlighten me what this rule means and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will quote HamletDRC (from the Microsoft team) who explained the rule itself very well:

> The point of the no-backbone-get-set-outside-model rule is to make
>   sure that you don't invoke dynamically dispatched methods that the
>   compiler cannot enforce correctness on. For example, the compiler will
>   not complain if you type route.params.get('id'),
>   route.params.get('ID'), route.params.get('Id') but only one of those
>   invocations will actually work at runtime. The design advice is to
>   define a statically typed "getId(): number" method on the RouteParams
>   object so the compiler can enforce these calls. So, in my opinion the
>   rule actually has found an issue in your code that you should fix (but
>   see my second point :) )

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/123

In this specific case one could extend the Redis class like this:

```
export class RedisWrapper extends Redis {
  public async getLocations(): Promise<ILocation[]> {
    const response: string = await this.get('locations');
    if (response == null || response.length === 0) { return []; }

    return <ILocation[]>JSON.parse(response);
  }
}
```